# Using MySql Workbench's import/export to copy a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**My goal is to:** **Copy a table** in the **same database** with the **same contents**, but with a **different table name.** If my table name is `device`, then I want to create another table with table name `device_test` in the same database. To do this, I tried the following steps:

In the Server menu:

```
1.  Data Export / Restore > Data Export
2.  Select the tables you want to export.
3.  Select "Export to Self-Contained File"
4.  Browse to the location for the SQL file.
5.  Start Export
```

Now, it's in the form of a .sql file on my desktop. Now if I import it into the same table using the following steps:

```
1.  Data Export / Restore > Data Import/Restore
2.  Import from Self-Contained File
3.  Browse to the location for the SQL file.
4.  Start Import
```

If I do this, is it going to overwrite the old table (`device`)?  If so, where I should specify the new table name (`device_test`)?

I am using MySQL Workbench, and I don't want to overwrite the original table.

Comment: can't you just use a basic SQL statment? `CREATE TABLE device_test LIKE device;
INSERT device_test SELECT * FROM device;`

Comment: I can use that, but just wanted to follow different approach.

Comment: After the dump .. Modify the file and then import it is the only alternative .

Comment: @Zak Right now the file is at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\dumps\Dump20140307.sql`, so I should change it to something like: `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\dumps\Dump211.sql` and then Import?

Comment: @John It doesn't matter where your file is saved, or what the name is (as long as it's still a .sql file).  If you export it, then import it again, *without modifying the content of the file*, you will lose your original table when you import it again.  You just need to edit the file.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Xynariz -- If you read the whole comment there are two lines  ...  Create table like , and insert selcet from ..

Comment: @Zak -- Well, you forgot `INTO`, which is necessary, but other than that, you are correct.  Hence why I deleted my comment doubting your accuracy.

Comment: Ahh Noted ..  I am unable to edit .. Otherwise I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the steps right, but you're missing one.  You have:

- Export File (which you describe correctly in your question)
- Import File (which you also describe correctly)

You should have:

- Export File
- ***Modify File***
- Import File

After you have exported the table, you will have a .sql file.  You can go into this file and modify it.  (You can open this file in any basic text editor.  If you're on Windows, you can open it in Notepad by right-clicking the file icon and selecting *Edit*.)  After some initial comments, you should have something like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `device`;    
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `device` ( 
 -- parameters, etc.
)
```

Note how it's dropping your table, then re-creating it?  It's simple - in both of those places where the table name is, change it to your *new* table name.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `device_test`;  -- note the new name
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `device_test` (  -- note the new name
 -- parameters, etc.
)
```

There are two other places in the file that this needs to be done.  One is in a `LOCK TABLES` statement, and the other is in the `INSERT INTO` statement.  (If you wish, you could simply use a Find\Replace tool to replace all instances of the old table name with the new name.)

You can then import it, and you're all set!

EDIT: As [Zak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507691/zak) mentioned in the comments to the question, one way of doing this could be to use `CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table; SELECT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;`.  If the two tables in question are on the same machine, etc, both methods will work.  However, the dump .sql file does have portability that cannot be mimicked using SQL statements.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. Probably it's a good idea to use a editor where one can use Replace All option to replace the table name so that there is not question of error as the device name was encountered two more times in addition to two times mentioned in the above answer. Thanks

Comment: @John Corrections duly noted, added to the answer.

Comment: Sorry to say so, but this solution is much to "heavy". I can't imagine how you'll open my 500 GB text file in Windows Notepad and edit it - nonsesce :)

Comment: @DarkSide That's the reason I suggested to use an editor to change the table name with"Replace All" option in it, just like Dreamweaver. I hope opening 500GB file in Notepad won't take long time?

Comment: @John, your solution surely works fine for small database dumps, but for big databases I guess even Dreamweaver will open such big dump file. Notepad will most likely die opening 500gb or bigger files - i must admit never tried such suicidal approach myself :)

Comment: @DarkSide I see. By the way, don't you think running `SELECT * ` over 500GB size table will behave in the same way?

Comment: @John, that surely will be slow but shouldn't be much slower than import from dump file where is multiple INSERTs. In fact, I believe one SELECT * FROM huge_table in theory should be faster than dump + edit + import. I'm not telling your solution is wrong, it's not! I have done like that myself couple of times with small test or development database, but not in production where you have a lot of data.

Comment: @DarkSide - There's no need for insults.  Yes, I agree that this solution is impractical for large data sets, but I was answering the question as asked.  "nonsesce" (as you spelled it) and suicidal are a bit harsh.

Comment: OK sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

or even shorter:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Comment: -1.  This was already mentioned in the comments to the question, and it doesn't solve the question asked.  Yes, this would be a better way than a dump, but that wasn't what the OP was asking.

Comment: @Xynariz Goal of the author of this question is "My goal is to: *Copy a table* in the same database with the same contents, but with a different table name." That's exactly what this code snippet do. I know I didn't mention about MySQL Workbench Import/Export because I believe it's not needed to do such easy task.

Comment: In my opinion DarkSide's answer is dead-on. I tested it and it works in split second. You see, there are time I too ask very confusing question or come up with a not  very efficient solution. So i am glad there are people like DarkSide would point me to a different but elegant solution. Thank you all.